# UITextView: Use original text color for links

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios9, core-text

I am using a UITextView with an NSAttributedString that contains links. I set the attributes I want to have for links. Unfortunately these are ignored by the UITextView and the linkTextAttributes of UITextView are used. Fine. But Is there a way to tell the UITextView to use the original color of the string for the link, not just one? Problem is that I have two text colors (for quotes and text) and if there is a link in the quote it will be displayed in the color set in the linkTextAttributes not in the original one.

Thanks for your help,
Philip

Answer (score 0):

So, yes, this is possible, I just found out how:

Set the colors and underlines you want to have in the attributed text and then only set the NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName and NSUnderlineColorAttributeName (or others) but not the NSForegroundColorAttributeName attribute. Now it works like a charm